# I am trying to deploy my MERN stack application on Heroku but I am getting following error

Tags: mern

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_adf85737_/client/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/build_adf85737_/client/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.B4J9l/_logs/2021-01-29T15_45_48_832Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 254
npm ERR! server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client`
npm ERR! Exit status 254
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.B4J9l/_logs/2021-01-29T15_45_48_856Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: it states 'Node version not specified in package.json' . have you checked your package.json